# CSV Export in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When trying csv export in rails, I am getting these values only

```
  `#<User:0x007f4a41859980> #<User:0x007f4a41835c88>
```

my controller file ps4_controller.rb

```
def csv_export
    @users = User.order(created_at: :desc)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @users.to_csv }
      format.xls { render text: @users.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
    end
  end
```

model file ps4.rb

```
class Ps4 < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :username, :email, :school, :batch

    def self.to_csv(users)
      CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        users.each do |ps4|
          csv << ps4.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

view file csv_export.xls.rb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Batch</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.username %></td>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td><%= user.school %></td>
          <td><%= user.batch %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anybody plz help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@users` is an array of users, and you are trying to call `to_csv` method on the array. On the other hand the `to_csv` method is defined as a class method, meaning you need to invoke it on the class itself:

```
 format.csv { render text: User.to_csv(@users) }
```

Answer (score 2):

In controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  ...
  format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Date.today}.csv" }
end
```

In model (do not send any attributes to **to_csv** method):

```
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w{id email}

  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    all.each do |user|
      csv << attributes.map{ |attr| user.send(attr) }
    end
  end
end
```